# Parsing Dynamic Json Object without keys

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

I am trying to parse remote json object that has dynamic key values. Here is my **json format**.

```
[
    {
        "Item": [
            {
                "Account": "Flowers",
                "Today": 1,
                "Tomorrow": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I couldn't use the POJO class here because the remote json keys are always dynamic. So, I tried with the way as below with Retrofit2.

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {

                Log.e("Here response is", response.body().toString() + " ");       // got "Here response is: [{"Item":[{"Account":"FLOWSERVE-FCD","Today":1,"Tomorrow":1}]}] "

                JsonArray responseArray= response.body().getAsJsonArray();

                try {
                    JsonObject jObj1 = (JsonObject) responseArray.get(0);
                    JsonArray jArray = jObj1.getAsJsonArray("Item");
                    JsonObject jObj2 = (JsonObject) jArray.get(0);

    // It is ok if we know the keys
    String value1 = jObj2.get("Account").toString();     // get FLOWSERVE-FCD
    String value2 = jObj2.get("Today").toString();      // get 1
    String value3 = jObj2.get("Tomorrow").toString();   // get 1

    // Here , I try for dynamic, but it got error
        ArrayList<String> dynamicKeys = new ArrayList<String>();   // create ArrayList to store dynamic keys later

                    for (int i = 0; i < jObj2.size(); i++) {
                        String str_image_url = jObj2.get(i);       //   although use "jObj2.keys(); it can't be used here.              
                        Log.e("Succcccc ", str_image_url);
                        dynamicKeys.add(str_image_url);
                    }



                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("Grrr Again", e.toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(context, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e("Grrr Error", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

It works well if we know the **json keys**, but it trapped for me with dynamic keys. So, any ideas or alternative ways are appreciating.

Comment: you can get the list of keys using https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#names()

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, you mean JSONArray.names()? I used "import com.google.gson.JsonArray;" not "import org.json.JSONArray;"

Comment: @pskink, I have read to an extend. I am a little unclear with JSONObject (org.json.JSONObject) Vs JsonObject(com.google.gson.JsonObject)

Comment: see `entrySet()` then (vs `keys()`)

Comment: that was JSONObject, not JSONArray, but not important. You can use JSONObject, or find equivalent method in JsonObject

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko,@pskink , now everything is going pretty well . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, 
**Remove this code**

```
for (int i = 0; i < jObj2.size(); i++) {
                        String str_image_url = jObj2.get(i);       //   although use "jObj2.keys(); it can't be used here.              
                        Log.e("Succcccc ", str_image_url);
                        dynamicKeys.add(str_image_url);
                    }
```

**Replace with below code**

```
 Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entries = jObj2.entrySet();
                for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : entries) {   
                    Log.e("Here keys", entry.getKey()); 
                    dynamicKeys.add(entry.getKey());
                    }
```

Comment: Great answer! save my time.Thanks!!

Comment: I have edited your answer to 100% fix my question and I will surely accept soon.

Comment: @ZarNiMyoSettWin you changed almost everything he typed, don't do that